# How do we find the equation of a polynomial function with three unknowns?

Tags: polynomials

I tried substituting the the x intercepts and 0 into the equations and solving for a and b, which didn't yield a result that made sense. I also tried dividing the function by (x+3) using polynomial long division but I am not sure what do with the information I get from that to determine the equation of the function.

f(x)=x^4+5x^3+ax^2+bx-6

x intercepts (-1,-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't list them, but if you know the $x$-intercepts of a polynomial equation, then you know the equation. I assume you're working over $\mathbb{R}$ so your polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ may have complex roots, but over $\mathbb{C}$ your polynomial will decompose as $f(x) = c(x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3)(x - a_4)$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and the $a_i's$ are the roots of $f(x)$ which may be complex.

Edit: So now that the original post has been updated, I see you know two roots of $f$ only. What we know is that both $f(-1) = 0$ and $f(-3) = 0 $. This will give you two equations in two unknowns, which can be solved for $a$ and $b$.